# Hosting Rails App on AWS `initialize': Cannot assign requested address - bind(2) for "public ipv4 address" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, web-hosting, ruby-on-rails-7

i am trying to host a rails app using aws, i created the ec2 instance (with ubuntu) and installed ruby and rails and all the dependencies and git cloned project from my github and when i run `bin/dev` or `rails s`, the server is running perfectly fine but i am not able to access it through `localhost:3000`, or `(public ip4 address given by aws)`, so i went added a new rule into Inbound Rules with custom TCP allowing port 3000
[image]

and when i start rails server again by using rails s -b (public ipv4 address given by aws)
i get the following error in console

[image]

```
`initialize': Cannot assign requested address - bind(2) for "public ipv4 address" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
```

how can i fix this? :')

(CONCLUSION: my server runs fine if i run rails s or bin/dev or but i am not able to access it through port 3000 so i added new inbound rule and if i run rails s -b (public ipv4 address given by aws), i get error in the console)

Comment: `netstat -tln | grep 3000` to see what's already using that port.